# How Do I Stop Stylesheet File Locking When Using Saxon?

Tags: .net, xslt, saxon

I am using the latest version of Saxon HE for .NET (9.7.0.18) and am seeing issues with my stylesheet files getting locked. The issue does not always occur immediately, but I will generally start to see the issue after several calls to the stylesheet. At that point, I will no longer be able to save changes to the stylesheet in question via a text editor until I recycle the application pool.

From what I am seeing so far, it appears that supporting stylesheets pulled in via xsl:import or xsl:include get locked, but top level stylesheets do not get locked.

I am able to reproduce the issue by creating a new MVC project and calling the following GetXslt2FO method. I do not see this issue when working with .NET XslCompiledTransform.

How can I stop the filesheet locks from occurring?

Here is my example code:

```
    public XsltExecutable GetExecutable(string stylesheetPath)
    {
        using (FileStream s = new FileStream(stylesheetPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            var processor = new Processor();
            var compiler = processor.NewXsltCompiler();
            compiler.BaseUri = new Uri(stylesheetPath);
            var executable = compiler.Compile(s);
            return executable;
        }
    }

    public string GetXslt2FO(string xsltFilePath, XDocument xml, Dictionary<string, string> args)
    {
        // Compile stylesheet
        var executable = GetExecutable(xsltFilePath);
        var declaredArgs = executable.GetGlobalParameters();

        // Do transformation to a destination
        var destination = new DomDestination();
        using (var inputStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            xml.Save(inputStream);
            inputStream.Position = 0;
            var transformer = executable.Load();
            FileInfo stylesheetFileInfo = new FileInfo(xsltFilePath);
            transformer.SetInputStream(inputStream, new Uri(stylesheetFileInfo.DirectoryName));
            foreach (var arg in args)
            {
                var matchingArgDeclaration = declaredArgs.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Key.LocalName.ToLower() == arg.Key.ToLower());
                if (matchingArgDeclaration.Key == null)
                {
                    transformer.SetParameter(new QName(arg.Key), new XdmAtomicValue(arg.Value));
                }
                else
                {
                    // try to load up the specific parameter type
                    // list is based on http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/#!dotnetdoc/Saxon.Api/XdmAtomicValue
                    XdmItemType argType = matchingArgDeclaration.Value.getDeclaredItemType();
                    var argTypeName = "";
                    if (argType != null &&
                        argType is XdmAtomicType)
                        argTypeName = ((XdmAtomicType)argType).Name.LocalName;
                    switch (argTypeName.ToLower())
                    {
                        case "boolean":
                            transformer.SetParameter(new QName(arg.Key), new XdmAtomicValue(Convert.ToBoolean(arg.Value)));
                            break;

                        case "integer":
                            transformer.SetParameter(new QName(arg.Key), new XdmAtomicValue(Convert.ToInt32(arg.Value)));
                            break;

                        case "decimal":
                            transformer.SetParameter(new QName(arg.Key), new XdmAtomicValue(Convert.ToDecimal(arg.Value)));
                            break;

                        case "float":
                            transformer.SetParameter(new QName(arg.Key), new XdmAtomicValue(Convert.ToSingle(arg.Value)));
                            break;

                        case "double":
                            transformer.SetParameter(new QName(arg.Key), new XdmAtomicValue(Convert.ToDouble(arg.Value)));
                            break;

                        case "anyuri":
                            transformer.SetParameter(new QName(arg.Key), new XdmAtomicValue(new Uri(arg.Value)));
                            break;

                        case "qname":
                            transformer.SetParameter(new QName(arg.Key), new XdmAtomicValue(new QName(arg.Value)));
                            break;

                        default:
                            transformer.SetParameter(new QName(arg.Key), new XdmAtomicValue(((arg.Value))));
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

            transformer.Run(destination);
        }

        return destination.XmlDocument.OuterXml;
    }
```

Comment: I've raised a Saxon issue here: please track it: https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/3275

Comment: Could you be more precise about the symptoms - what tells you that a file is locked?

Comment: I have updated my question details. Once the file is locked, I am no longer able to save changes to it via a text editor.

Comment: We have reproduced the bug issue and resolved it. The patch will be available in the next maintenance release of Saxon 9.7. Please note the bug is not present in Saxon 9.8, so might be worth upgrading.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was only looking at what was available on Nuget, so I did not realize that there was a 9.8 version. I see the newer version now on the [Saxon SourceForge site](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/#F9.8HE).

Comment: The 9.8.0.2 release is now out and fixes this bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a Saxon bug and is fixed in maintenance release 9.8.0.2. Thank you for reporting it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the native .NET version SaxonCS (11.3.0) is locking the stylesheets again.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. To make your answer useful to OP and to others, be sure to explain how to resolve the problem in detail, and not just expressing the obvious. This answer looks a lot more like a comment than a useful answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).